# Iterate Through Table and use multiple values from each row

Tags: excel, vba

I have worksheet 1 that I'm already running a loop for each cell. That cell needs to be formatted according to multiple values from a table on worksheet 2. These values need to be compared row by row to determine what color to make the cell on worksheet 1.

For instance:
On worksheet 1, cell A3 the formula needs to iterate through each row on Table1 of Worksheet 2 and take the 1st column, 2nd column and 3rd column of EACH row of Table1 to make a decision on what color cell A3 is going to be. Then it will go to the next cell in Worksheet 1.

I already have the loop that goes to each cell in Worksheet 1. I'm having trouble figuring out how to iterate through a table by row and be able to reference multiple values in the same row for if statements and comparing dates.

Does anyone have any advice or resources? Through my research I've found that arrays may be able to accomplish this task, but I'm not quite sure how this would look.

Comment: Adam - welcome to StackOverflow; it sounds like you're on the right track but please provide the code so we can help troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: I haven't written the code on iterating through a table/selecting information from the rows because I'm not quite sure how to write it. That's the only part I need help on. I don't mind if you were to write your own interpretation on how to do that - I think I'm capable of integrating it into the code I have now. Due to the nature of the project I'm working on - it is physically impossible for me to copy/paste it onto here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using arrays.

```
For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
    value1 = arr(i, 1)
    value2 = arr(i, 2)
    value3 = arr(i, 3)
End If
```

It ended up being very simple.